# Why do we consider current to be constant throughout a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

Let us consider a circuit made up of connecting wires, a resistor, a switch and a battery. Now, the resistance of the resistor is much higher than that of the wire. Now, intuitively, I am thinking that current flow would be less in the resistor than the wires. But, I have read at many places where they write that the current is constant at every point of the circuit, which seems a little confusing to me.

Another version of the same question: The potential difference between any two points of the *wire* and that of the *resistor* would be different, and their resistances are already different. Then, why is the ratio $\Delta V/R$ constant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why current through all the resistors in series is considered to be same?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80966)

Comment: This is only true on average when considering AC systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current is charge per second passing by. Think of the consequences if at one spot more current was flowing than in another spot.

- If at spot A the current is *smaller* than in a later spot B, then less is flowing in every second than what is flowing out. After some time there wouldn't be any more charge to flow out. So in the end the outflow at spot B can't be larger than the inflow at spot A.
- If at spot A the current is *larger* than in a later spot B, then more flows in than out. So every second there will be more and more charge stored in between those spots. A growing charge means a larger and larger repulsion against the incoming charge, slowing it down, and a larger and larger push on the outflowing charge, speeding it up. This will continue to speed up and slow down until outflow is larger. Then the stored charge will be less and less and soon none is stored anymore, and inflow will balance outflow as described before now that outflow is larger.

Only outcome for a steady current that doesn't stop is that inflow equals outflow of charge at any point.

Answer (score 5):

Current is the movement of charges through the wire. Since charge is conserved, it has to be the same at any given point in a closed circuit without branches, otherwise the circuit would be leaking.

An often cited analogy would be a system of water pipes. It might be more difficult for the water to squeeze through narrow pipes (high resistance) but the total volume of water per unit time (the water current) that flows through the narrow pipe is the same at any given point as water is for all practical purposes incompressible.