# Why is the current equal when the resistors are in series?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

I am a High schooler.
And I learned that the current is always the same when the resisters are in series.
[image: Circuit]

I was told about the water analogy.
If the first one had had a smaller resistance wouldn't it slow down the current a bit and the larger one will slow it down even more?
which would mean they would measure different currents?
What am I not able to understand here?

I got some explanations saying that current is not velocity.
But It does look like velocity in this simulation.

[Circuit Construction Kit: DC](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulations/circuit-construction-kit-dc)

How is it different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current in series resistors and voltage drop in parallel resistors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43782/)

Comment: I am still confused

Comment: I tried to read it again and now I think I got something I was confusing current which is q/t with velocity. Now it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Current is not just the speed of the flow. It is the amount of charge passing a given point per unit time. If it is not the same amount all around the loop forming the circuit then that means the charge must be building up somewhere, and falling away somewhere else. This cannot go on forever so it can't be happening if the situation is in a steady state with a steady current.

With two resisters, *both* contribute to the overall restriction of the flow. The current settles at the value where the 'shove' provided by the voltage source matches the overall restriction provided by the *total* resistance.

Comment: I was confusing current which is q/t with velocity?
But wouldn't that mean in the middle the value of q per t will be smaller?

Answer (score 2):

I read your underlying question as, what is the difference between current and the velocity of charges?

## Current is more complicated than charge flow

The first thing to say is, current can flow even when charge cannot. So there are these components that we call capacitors, charges cannot flow through them, but electrical current can. Especially AC, alternating current, can: this is a sort of “sound wave” propagation of energy that can propagate through the insulator in the capacitor. But direct current, DC, can too—for a little while.

Another example of the propagation of current without charge is a transformer. In a transformer you have two separate coils of wire, they do not connect to each other, but because they share an iron core between them, an AC current from one coil gets transmitted to the other coil.

The second thing to say is, charges can move from one point to another. But we usually don't say that current can, electric current always has to flow in loops. So that's another curious difference between the motion of charges, and current. We usually regard current as a steady thing moving in circles, coming in these two varieties of direct and alternating. Sure, the motion of electric charges has *something to do with it* because it’s the most common form of transmission.

When DC flows through a capacitor, the fact that the charges cannot go through the insulator still *matters* of course: it means that a certain number of positive charges build up on one side of the insulator and a corresponding equal negative charge builds up on the other side of the insulator. This causes a voltage change. This change in voltage can be regarded as a different sort of electric current, called “displacement current.”

## How this answers your other question

If you understand this basic fact about current, the reverse is your question. You want to know why the currents in the two resistors have to be exactly the same. And the answer is they don't, in reality you have a small capacitance between the “island of wire” between the resistors, and the ground. You can draw this in as a capacitor if you like.

But, this capacitor has a very low capacitance. It wasn't built to hold a lot of charge. Usually when we build capacitors we use big flat sheets, and there's a reason for this, it's that the two-dimensional geometry leads to a force, an electric field, that does not diminish with distance. But in the case of these two wires, the field does diminish with distance, like $1/r$ if the wires are close together or like $1/r^2$ if they are even further apart. In addition, with parallel plates usually the insulator is chosen to have a good dielectric coefficient, so light goes slowly in that medium, so you get more charge stored per unit of field. But between these wires you've got air and that has about the same permittivity as free space, light goes at the speed of light. And finally with these parallel plates we try to make them as big as we reasonably can, that gives the charges a bit more space to spread out. But with your wires they are very small. In a breadboard, you can get picofarads of coupling between nearby rows though... it's not nothing! If you were to put a megaohm of resistance between the two, then a picofarad creates a capacitor which charges and discharges over a timescale of microseconds. (It's just $\tau = RC.$) So you will especially see these effects on a breadboard as you get into megahertz+ AC signals.

Now, even if you put a capacitor there you would discover that it doesn't really matter if you have direct current. And the reason why is that under direct current, the capacitor saturates. It charges up to some value and then no more current goes through it. So that has a very straightforward interpretation as your electron speeds: if you think about electrons flowing through this thing, and they go faster through one resistor then the other, then the wire in the middle is going to have either too many or too few electrons. It will have too many if the “upstream” or “incoming” flow of electrons is higher, or too few if the “downstream” or “outgoing” flow is higher. In the first case, it will have a negative charge, and this will repel other electrons: it will push more electrons downstream while resisting electrons coming in from upstream. So the electrons will have to settle into an equilibrium, the flows will have to come to be the same because any mismatch in the flows creates a charge which pushes the electrons involved in a way that brings the system back into balance.

So, on this breadboard, with DC current, you might find that if you counted all of the electrons going around the loop, there's a shortage. Maybe a billion electrons stay on the island of breadboard wire between the two resistors, attracted to an adjacent breadboard wire that you have grounded. But, the effect only lasts for this microsecond or so, because at that point the number of electrons stabilizes. This is the right number of electrons to push back on the incoming electrons and push out on the outgoing electrons, to keep this island at however many volts it is. And meanwhile, the only current that has gone into this capacitive coupling is something like a tenth of a milliamp or less, for this tiny fraction of a second.

So this capacitance between these two places is very small and in practice we ignore it completely, just because “a blink of an eye” (human reaction time) is 100 ms or so and a microsecond is very short for us—it's much longer for computers, which do things billions of times a second, so these capacitive couplings usually are of more interest to computer manufacturers. But the point is you're in high school and you'll kind of believe us even if we tell you nonsense and so we tell you to just ignore the things happening at microseconds unless you become an electrical engineer and work at a computer chip maker.

Answer (score 1):

Current is the rate of flow of charge. If there is only one path for the charge to flow the current can't change.

In the water analogy, the rate of flow of water represents the current. For the water to be moving nicely through the whole circuit it has to be all moving at the same speed, therefore current stays the same in a series circuit.

Comment: I don't understand, Why can't the current slow down a little bit first and then slow down even more because of even more resistance?

Comment: Imagine a closed water pipe with a turbine pushing the water around it. The water can't be going faster in one place because then there will be gaps in the circuit and water will be built up in one place. Current doesn't slow down at all.

Comment: Doesn't current mean coulombs per second? 
Why can't it decrease?

Comment: It can't decrease because then charge will get built up. If its going faster in one place the faster charge will catch up to the charge that's going slower and all the charge will end up in the same place.

Comment: are u saying it would always remain the same?

Comment: In a series circuit yes.

Comment: But why? I don't understand

Comment: it's been explained on the thread 50 times. Ask your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way, Tushar.

You're correct, a resister does lower current.  But they don't *hold charge* like a capacitor.

So the same current going in, has to be going out.  Otherwise charge would be building up inside the resister infinitely.

You can almost think of it like a checkpoint to get into a stadium.  It slows things down, yes.  But if only 10 people are allowed to wait in line at the same time, and the line is full, then someone can not enter the line until someone leaves the checkpoint.  Therefore the rate at which people enter the line is the same as the rate at which people exit the line+checkpoint.

Going back to the water analogy you're familiar with, we actually need to look at *two* things to understand what's happening:  flow (current), and pressure (voltage).

If you have a hose with flowing water, and you go to the middle of the hose and pinch it a bit, you just added resistance (a resistor) to that parts of the hose (circuit).  But the water flowing toward your pinch has to be the same as the water flowing *out* of your pinch.  Otherwise, where would the buildup of water stay?  So your pinch (resistor) has reduced flow (current) for the entire hose (circuit), not just one spot.

Now, if you were to measure pressure (voltage) after your pinch (resistor), it would be very low, since there is nothing standing in the way between  your pinch (resistor) and the hose's exit.

But before your pinch (resistor) there would be a higher pressure (voltage) because water is being pushed toward the pinch and can't get through fast enough.

So pressure (voltage) before and after your pinch (resistor) will have dropped.

Comment: Is current the same as the charge?
I thought it was defined as q/t. if it will be slowed after one resister wouldn't that mean that in the same amount of time less charge would travel?

Comment: Current is charge per time (nothing to do with velocity, which is distance over time).

Since current is q/t, pick some t.  Any t.  1 second, 1 hour, 1 day,

Over the course of that t, the same total q that went into the resistor should be the same q that left the resistor.

Comment: I am not able to visualize this. Any video that you know of?

Comment: @TusharMaharana which part do you find difficult to visualize?

Is any part of the hose, the pinch, and the pressure/flow clear?

Comment: I am confused about the difference between current and velocity because in this simulation [link](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulations/circuit-construction-kit-dc)
It is shown as velocity.

Comment: Flow is not the same as velocity.  For example, you can have an extremely fast moving stream of water coming out of a small pipe, and you can have very slow moving water coming out of an absolutely massive pipe.  The slower water coming from the massive pipe can be a higher flow despite being  slower speed.

That animation chooses to illustrate flow using velocity, but it's not velocity.

Comment: Take a minute to think on this:  Flow is *how much* crosses a point.  it is not *how fast*.

Comment: I am so confused will I ever be able to understand this?
But I will try to think of that.

Comment: I finally get it. I was not considering that would slow down the entire current in the circuit not only in the ressistor.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to equate current with water velocity.  The correct thing to equate it to is water *flow rate*, say Liters per second or Gallons per second.  In a steady water flow, the fluid can speed up or slow down as you are thinking, but slower flow in a larger pipe area is the same flow rate.  If flow rate were higher in one area than another, water would either be piling up in a corner of a pipe or else pulling away from itself and creating voids.  Neither of these can happen because of conservation of mass.

It is the same with electrical current. If the current in a closed loop were not the same everywhere, you would have electrons piling up in somewhere (this actually happens in a capacitor, but after a short time the current flow stops, as you'd expect).