# Electricity - Why is current, same throughout a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, charge, electrical-resistance

In a circuit containing resistors, the current remains the same throughout. This can be verified by Ohm's Law. But by the expression $I = q/t$, the charges passing through the resistor reduces per second. Then how the value of current remains same all over?

Comment: Current is not generally the same around a circuit. Do you mean a simple loop circuit with nothing but a battery and a single  resistor?

Comment: "But by the expression I = q/t, the charges passing through the resistor reduces per second." What makes you think that?

Comment: $I = q/t$ doesn't mean there's a fixed charge ($q$) divided by the time.  It's a definition of current _per unit charge_.  Current is charge _flow_, and can be continuous, just like water in a river.

Comment: If you need a more visible example, consider v=d/t for a constant velocity.  t is the time traveling and d is the total distance covered from t=0 to the current time.  Your interpretation is as if treating d as a standard unit of distance, perhaps a mile.  v=d/t doesn't mean (one mile)/(total time), but it can mean (one mile)/(time to travel only one mile).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current in series resistors and voltage drop in parallel resistors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43782/current-in-series-resistors-and-voltage-drop-in-parallel-resistors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> by the expression I = q/t, the charges passing through the resistor reduces per second

That is an incorrect interpretation of that expression. In fact, if $I$ is constant then since $t$ obviously increases linearly with time that means $q$ also increases linearly with time.

However, in circuits $q$ is rarely a useful quantity. In this expression it would be the total amount of charge that has passed by some point in the circuit. The only place that tends to be useful is in a capacitor, and even then rarely.

Answer (score 6):

If you speak of  single loop (where all moving charge must travel the same path), then the current is the same throughout because any charge entering a part of the loop must also leave that part.  If current out was smaller than current in, then more charge would enter per second than the amount that left per second.  Total charge in that portion of a loop, perhaps a battery or resistor, would get larger and larger until the electric charge caused it to explode as all of the electrons pushed each other away.  It is voltage that changes from point to point along the circuit.  This is POTENTIAL energy per unit charge.  Kinetic energy in the moving charges remains essentially the same, keeps a fairly steady average throughout for a simple DC circuit.  The energy that drives elements of a circuit comes from potential energy provided by the power source.  The current determines the rate at which this energy is delivered through the circuit.

Comment: Okay,if resistance does not affect the current, what does it actually does ? What is it's role ?

Comment: Resistance does affect current, the current throughout the entire circuit.  More resistance slows the rate at which current flows because energy from the voltage must be used to push the current through the resistor.  A resistor is often a very narrow piece of wire within a material created to prevent the wire from burning up.  Like water through a narrow tube, a slow current flows more easily than a fast current.  The resistor requires less energy per unit of charge when the current is slow.

Comment: @RohitMadhavPL when I turn the faucet off does the water flow in the pipes decrease? Yes? well does that mean the water flow before the tap is greater than the water flow after the faucet?

Comment: @user253751 onsider the pressure drop you may experience while showering and someone flushes the toilet or opens a tap in the kitchen.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe so is the water flow before the faucet greater than the water flow after the faucet? is water somehow building up inside the faucet? does the faucet inflate like a balloon?

Comment: @user253751 if it is turned off (closed), the flow is equal before and after , while if it is open the flow after it is smaller by the amount of flow that comes out of the faucet. (I guess a balloon at the end would be similar to a capacitor). The faucet is where the hydraulic analogy breaks down a little as the open tap spills the water to effectively a "ground path", while a wire that terminates in nothing would obviously be an open circuit. Either way, the open tap and the rest of the pipe after the tap are two parallel circuits.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe so the amount of water that goes into the faucet is larger than the amount that comes up? does it inflate like a balloon?

Answer (score 5):

You have used a common, but misleading, definition of a current. The equation should read $$I = \frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t},$$ which makes it clear that a current is change in the charge contained in a given region over an interval of time. If you could observe the charge flow in a wire (or through a resistor), you would "see" an amount of charge $\Delta Q$ pass a given point during the time interval $\Delta t$, and this would constitute a current of I during that time interval.

Of course, currents can be time-varying, and in the limit the definition of current is really a derivative of the charge $$I(t) = \frac{\delta Q(t)}{\delta t}.$$